# JS Array.Prototype.find() returning wrong value after match

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript.Prototype.find() is not working how I expect. It's matching against an object, but it's returning the value in the array *after* the match.

I have this array:

```
[
    { "src": "/api/health-check", "dest": "/api/health-check.js"},
    { "src": "/api/user", "dest": "/api/services/user" },
    { "src": "/api/auth", "methods": ["GET"], "dest": "/api/services/auth/index.js" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/app/$1" }
]
```

It passes through this:

```
  const route = routes.find(
      ({ src, methods }) => {
        console.log("Does it match?", (!methods || methods.indexOf(req.method) !== -1) && req.url.match(new RegExp(`^${src.replace(/\(\?<[a-z]+>/, '(')}$`)))
        return (
          (!methods || methods.indexOf(req.method) !== -1) &&
          req.url.match(new RegExp(`^${src.replace(/\(\?<[a-z]+>/, '(')}$`))
        )
      }
    )
```

The "Does it match?" console.log() logs each route as null, until it reaches the route I want which is "/api/auth", it logs that match, and then the loop stops. It does not continue to the next route which is "(.*)".

But when I log the route value immedately after the find function, this is the vale that gets assigned to the route variable.

```
This is the found route { src: '/(.*)', dest: '/app/$1' }
```

It's as if the find function is accurately finding the matching route and then giving me the route after the match.

Comment: Do you mind showing how you log the route after the `find`?

Comment: Could you provide more of your javascript. What loop are you refering to?

Comment: What does your `req` variable look like?

Comment: Seems to be working here with an appropriately defined `req`: https://jsfiddle.net/yhuzqw1n/

Comment: The incoming req.url logs out like this:

`console.log("This is the req", req.url)`

`This is the req /api/auth/signin`

Comment: Oh, wow. Ok now we're making progress. Thank you for that jsfiddle Aioros. The route you used in the req 'api/auth/' works, but if I make it 'api/auth/signin', it gives me the next item from the find loop.

Comment: Great, so it's mostly a matter of how you match the regex. You could simply remove the `$` at the end of it, unless you need to match urls with the same suffix (like /api/foo and api/foobar). I would suggest making sure that all url strings involved end with a `/` before comparison.

Comment: @AndrewStover Well the regex `/^\/api\/auth$/` won't match the request url `api/auth/signin`. Are you sure you're getting the "*Does it match?*" output from that route?

Comment: Yes, I edited [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n0whef7/1/) to show an 'api/auth/signin' req. It lists null, null, null, and then logs the matched route which I would assume would resolve to 'truthy' for .find() loop.

What I would like is for any request to 'api/auth/(x)' to resovle to 'api/auth' where there is an express server waiting to do the final bit of routing problematically. It does work, though if I just make all of my route mappings explicit, e.g. api/auth/signin or api/user/get-user so I guess I'll just do that. Thank you for the help everyone.